# Assigning new values to a variable (in R)

Tags: r

I have a df (data) in which I have each participant twice (two time points). However, I don't have a variable yet which indicates if its data from the first or second time point. What I would like to have in the end is a variable called "order" which is 0 for the first time point and 1 for the second time point.

I have a variable which is called startTime which has the following format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss for both time points.

Comment: If it's sorted by participant and time, you can do `df$var <- 0:1`. The value on the right will "recycle", which is a basic feature of R you can read about in the introductory documentation. (I didn't downvote, but folks are probably doing that because you haven't shown "research effort".)

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at the example (which is bad), I'd advice something like

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(something) %>%
   arrange(startTime) %>%
   mutate(
      order = n() - 1
   )
```

Can't say no more.